# PHP date function is returning wrong month and date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have been working in PHP Development for 5 years but never seen this type of error before.

I have a date which is the last day of the month and I am going to change its format with using below code :

```
$data['toDate'] = "2017-04-31";
echo $data['toDate']." : ".date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data['toDate']))." ### ";
die;
```

It outputs :

> 2017-04-31 00:00:00 : 01-05-2017 ###

I am working on PHP version 5.6.25.
Is there anyone can help me in this??

Comment: This is because April doesn't have date 31.

Comment: Are you serious? https://i.imgur.com/PESvU18.png

Answer (score 2):

The 31th April don't exist. Because of that PHP going to the day after the 30th April

Answer (score 1):

April only has 30 days, so it's actually correcting the date your using.  The 31st would really be the 1st of May.

Answer (score 0):

Its wrong with input, not with `date()`.

```
$data['toDate'] = "2017-04-31";// no 31st in 4th(April) month
echo $data['toDate'] ." : ". date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data['toDate']))." ### ";
die;
```

Its just showing up next date which is `01-05-2017`

Comment: Ohh!!! lol... Sorry my mistake... thank you...

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

04-31 is valid but not technically a date in [April](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/months/april.html), since [April](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/months/april.html) only has 30 days and thus [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) yields 05-01.

#### Documentation

If you look at the documentation for [strtotime()](http://PHP.net/strtotime) you will see the first parameter is:

> **time**
>   A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

If you follow the link for the date and time formats and go to [*Date Formats*](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) you will see:

[image]

Thus for the date format (I.e. *DD*), 01-31 is valid    (since a *3* can only be followed by a *0* or *1*) despite the month. Depending on the supplied month and date value the date will be adjusted.

Also found in the notes on that same page:

> **Note**:
>   It is possible to over- and underflow the *dd* and *DD* format. Day 0 means the last day of previous month, whereas overflows count into the next month. This makes "2008-08-00" equivalent to "2008-07-31" and "2008-06-31" equivalent to "2008-07-01" (June only has 30 days).<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)</sup>

Hence *04-31* is valid but overflows.

Additionally, in the [User Contributed Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php#usernotes) section, the [note by Mirek at 2015-04-01 01:14](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php#117014) might be useful/interesting:

> Note: the day (dd or DD) is first checked for range 0..31 and only if it fits, the overflow and underflow mechanism may apply. If not, strtotime() simply returns false.
>   If you need unlimited over/underflow for date calculations (for example 2015-01-40 to 2015-02-09), use [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) instead.<sup>[2](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php#Hcom117014)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php#Hcom117014</sub>